# How to set the cells Textlabels indention correctly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i´m writing some kind of product list within an TableView.

My problem is that some cells have an image and some don´t furthermore the images don´t have the same width.

The problem is that the textlabel and the detailtextlabel do not indent vertically aligned over all of the cells. But i need all textlabels accurately under each other.

I already figured out that the properties "indentationLevel" and "indentationWidth" can modify the behaviour - but i don´t get them working fine...

For example: If i use these lines of code - all my textlabels become indented - but not the same indention over all cells.

```
cell.imageView.image   = [UIImage imageNamed:item.nameImage];
cell.indentationLevel  = 1;
cell.indentationWidth  = 30.0f;
```

Thanks in advance

Boris

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom `UILable` set as cell `accessoryView` if it is suitable. All `UILable`s you use in that case should have similar frames.